# how to import .rec files in R

Tags: r, rodbc, european-data-format

I have a .rec file that I want to import into R. I have saved the .rec file to my working directory. This is what I have tried.

```
library(foreign)  
library(RODBC)  
data.test <- read.epiinfo("data_in.rec")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in if (headerlength <= 0L) 
stop("file has zero or fewer variables: probably not an EpiInfo file") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

In addition: Warning messages:

1:

```
In readLines(file, 1L, ok = TRUE) :
  line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
```

2:

```
In strsplit(line, " ") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

I have looked online and in the read.epiinfo help package in R. The help package says

> Some later versions of Epi Info use the Microsoft Access file format
>   to store data. That may be readable with the RODBC package.

I have two questions.
1. Is the error I am getting because the .rec file I have is from an Epi Info version later than 6?
2. How do I use the RODBC library to open the .rec file?

Comment: I don't know what a `.rec` file is, but the error strongly suggests that the file is unrecognizable (perhaps corrupted or empty). If you look at the file manually (notepad++, less, ...), does it look right to you? Does `file.info("CF031_22FEB2016.rec")$size` look right to you? (I wouldn't know.) BTW: how can something have fewer than zero variables? That's a perplexing error ...

Comment: Thank You for the editing. The.rec file is a time series recording of Polysomnograph (EEG) data. The file.info("CF031_22FEB2016.rec")$size gives me a file size of 1004614016.

Comment: Was this Polysomnograph (EEG) data exported from Epi Info?

Comment: To be honest @Stedy I am not sure. It was given to me by the clinician. I have google .rec files and it tells me that they are Epi Info files.

Comment: ok, then I would try the comment from @r2evans - try opening in a text editor (Notepad, notepad++, less, etc) and taking a look at the file. You might even be able to read it into R with `read.table()`

Comment: @r2evans  I have opened the file in TextEdit, the file is not empty. The beginning of file gives the EEG variables being measured and the units. I will try the read.table() command.

Comment: @Stedy I have opened the file in TextEdit, the file is not empty. The beginning of file gives the EEG variables being measured and the units. I will try the read.table() command.

Comment: The program that recorded and probably exported the data in Sandman Software

Comment: This software? https://healthmanagement.org/products/view/diagnostic-software-polysomnography-sandman-r-elite-natus-medical-incorporated You might be better off just using that to export data as a CSV file then analyze in R

Comment: It turns out that the data is an European Data Format file. I was able to open it using the R library edfReader. Thank you for your help @Stedy

Comment: yeah! you should write that up as an answer so that other people can find it. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

The .rec (or .REC) file turned out to be a .EDF (European Data Format) file type. It was easily opened in R using the library edfReader. The edfReader library help file is very useful for opening the file and extracting the time series data. See code below for what I used. Code was adapted from the help file.

```
install.packages('edfReader')
library(edfReader)
?edfReader  
lib.dir <- system.file("data_in.rec",package="edfReader")  
Cfile <- paste(lib.dir,'/edfPlusC.edf',sep='')  
CHdr <- readEdfHeader("data_in.rec")  
CSignals <- readEdfSignals(CHdr)  
summary(CSignals)
```